# Feature transformation possible at selected features or only at all?

Tags: feature-scaling, clustering

I want to cluster. I have different features for that. Some features have a very small value range (from 0 to 0.8) and some have a very large value range (from 0 to 5 million). I want to use the logarithm. Do I have to apply this feature transformation to all features, including the small values (shift the values before by +1) or can I just choose the features I want to do the transformation on? Is there any literature or work on this?

Answer (score 1):

Either can be good or bad. It's not necessary to apply the same transformation to all attributes; but if youe attributes differ that much, you likely have some major problem anyway.

It depends on what you want to achieve what is appropriate. Try to approach it from having to *explain* your choices later. Can you argue why you transform the data this way? What is the statistical meaning of this transform for your problem? Here you'll quickly realize that with mixed data you can't really argue much - your results are based on guessing, not in a sound model.

Comment: First of all many thanks for your answer! 
But I have two more question. Wouldn't it be okay to say, I take the logarithm from the features with the large value range, because it is skewed data and the data even gets a smaller value range? Would that be not statistically correct? 
I want to get the data to the same value range, because it plays a role in the distance measurement of the cluster algorithm. Without transforming my data, the clusters aren't good.

Comment: A "large" value range itself is not a sufficient argument for a long scale. Skewedness is, if the data becomes less skewed afterwards. You may still need to adjust the range afterwards. Technically you will never really have the same value range though.

Comment: I really don't find any paper saying that feature scaling can only be applied to selected features. Do you have a tip for me? 
I'm not sure if I can only apply the log to the feature with the large value range and not to the feature with the value range 0 and 0.8 (or after the shift plus 1 --> 1 and 1.8).

Comment: You don't need to cite a paper. *Obviously* you can transform each column independently. But you should have good arguments for the transformation you choose, including that "shift". Why not sqrt instead?

Comment: I don't think it is that obvious and neither is my professor. My task is to find a paper, but I really don't find one. And that surprises me.

Comment: People have always been transforming variables independently. I am not surprised that you don't find a paper... Because there is nothing to write on this matter.

Comment: Thank you very much! What are good arguments when my goal is to make skewed data less skewed? Do I always take to the features the transformation that gives me the lesser skew? Or are there other things (e.g. the variance) that I have to consider?

Comment: If you want to use an algorithm that assumes unskewed data, then removing skew is good. If you don't, then you don't need to remove skew.

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce skewness. But how do I do this for the features? Is there a criterion I have to pay attention to? Or do you just test it out? How do I know which transformation is best for the feature I'm looking at?  Do I just use the BoxCox?

Comment: Depends on what you know about the features. If they are generated from a lognormal distribution, taking the log may be most appropriate. So it depends on what you know of and hypothesize of the features. There is no "always right" approach.

Comment: I know it's count data that has a high skew. Does it make sense to transform the data differently? For example, if the skew of one feature gets lower with the log transformation and the other feature gets lower with the cube root transformation?

Comment: Skew statistics are estimates, and may be misleading. Consider the data generating process, not just the output.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The skew computation does not always work right. Also, not all skrw needs to be removed. It depends on how the data is generated, too. I.e. the **why is the data skewed** is necessary to decide on how to best remove the skew (or whether to not remove it at all).

Comment: For example when you do log(1+x) on count data, but your values are mostly small, then you get large gaps there that can still ruin your analysis. Skew is not your main problem then with k-means.